# Update hyperlinks in shapes when file location changes

Tags: vba, hyperlink, path, updates, shapes

I have a process flow diagram that uses various excel shapes to visually represent a data production process from start to finish, I.e. from data input to analytic environment to data output to submission file.  I have used vba to hyperlink many of the shapes in the diagram to another sheet in the workbook (using thisworkbook.fullname) that contains definitions for abbreviations contained in the text of each shape, eg C1 is listed in a shape, the hyperlink takes you to the definition tab cell where C1 is defined as control point one.  The hyperlinks work when the xlsm workbook is in my home location where i saved the file but they do not work if I save the file to another location (they try to open my original workbook).  Is it as easy as changing the hyperlink addresses to thisworkbook.filename and dropping the path to make this work? do i need to create a macro that will automatically look up the old hyperlink address and replace it with the new address of current file location for every shape in the workbook containing a hyperlink. The path could change in the future, so want it to be relative and not fixed - for example if I save the file to share point and another user saves a copy to their home directory, I still want the links to work for them in either location. Some hyperlinks go to "sheet1" some to "sheet2" for example, but sheets 1 & 2 are both located in the same workbook. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveWorkbook.Name solves the problem, replace ThisWorkbook.FullName with it and hyperlink works in other directories.